# UIScreenEdgeRecognizerGesture smooth like safari

Tags: swift, animation, uigesturerecognizer

My container view controller has a screen edge pan gesture to change the views. The code for panning the views looks as follows:

```
func changeView(recognizer: UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer) {

    println("INITIAL: \(recognizer.translationInView(view))")

    if recognizer.state == .Began {
        // Create and configure the view

        println("BEGAN: \(recognizer.translationInView(view))")
    }

    if recognizer.state == .Changed {
        println("CHANGED: \(recognizer.translationInView(view))")

        let translation = recognizer.translationInView(view)

        currentView.view.center.x += translation.x
        pendingView.view.center.x += translation.x

        recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: view)
    }

    if recognizer.state == .Ended {
        if recognizer.view!.center.x > view.bounds.size.width {
            // Animate the view to position
        } else {
            // Animate the view back to original
        }
    }
}
```

While this works, I'm still having an issue with the start of the panning. When a user swipes quickly, `translation` will have a value big enough to make the start of the pan looking "unsmoothly".

For example, with a quick swipe `translation` will start with a value of `100`. The value is then added to the `center.x` of the views causing the undesired effect.

I noticed Safari has a screen edge gesture as well to change views and this effect doesn't occur no matter how quick the swipe is. Nor does this happen with a normal `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

I've tried wrapping the "animation" in `UIView.animateWithDuration()`. It does look more smooth, but then it feels it's just lagging behind the actual gesture, unlike how it's done in Safari.

Can someone please tell me a better way to pan the views so it will look as smooth as in Safari?

**EDIT:**
I've added several lines to check the value of the translation and the problem is it jumps from `0` to some value causing the unwanted behavior. It doesn't matter where I put `recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: view)`.

The output is:

```
INITIAL: (21.5, 0.0)
BEGAN:   (21.5, 0.0)
INITIAL: (188.0, -3.0)
CHANGED: (188.0, -3.0)
```

After some more testing:

```
func changeView(recognizer: UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer) {
    println("INITIAL: \(recognizer.translationInView(view))")
    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: view)
}

INITIAL: (0.0, 0.0)
INITIAL: (130.5, -35.5)
```

**FINAL:**
Seems like creating and preparing the new view is causing some kind of minor lag in `Began`. The small amount of lag is enough to create a difference in translation of 100-200.

Probably have to preload the views somewhere else I guess.

Comment: Well, maybe something else is going, because my tests don't agree with yours (I added some logging results to my answer). Is your gesture recognizer in conflict with something else, so that it is taking it a lot of time just to decide to recognize?

Comment: I was about to update my question. It seems creating the view is causing some kind of lag in `Began`. I guess I'll have to preload the views somewhere else? (Creating the new view involves using `filter` 4 or 5 times, passing some values and the usual child/parent setup)

Comment: Well just use the delegate methods to prioritize the conflicting gesture recognizers. - I will add that to my answer.

Comment: Very much appreciated. Was reading your line over and over and afraid to upset you by not understanding :p Btw, one small off topic question. Hope it's allowed here. Is your latest book recommended for starters/intermediates?

Comment: I'll just say this: everything in my answer came straight out of the book.

Comment: So you think the lag is due to what you are doing in the `began` section? You should instrument your code by logging some times to see if that's true.

Comment: Yea, I started commenting out line for line and at the point where the view is actually created. To create this view, I instantiate a view controller from the storyboard, pass some values and filter some stuff out with `filter` (3 times). If I comment it out, everything will be smooth.

Comment: Nice detective work!

Answer (score 1):

This won't solve all your problems, since, as you have rightly said, a screen edge pan gesture recognizer is a little crusty in its behavior; but do note that you are omitting one valuable piece of data - the question of what `recognizer.translationInView` is *in the `.Began` state*. At that time, obviously, the finger has *already* moved considerably; for, if it had not, we would not have recognized this as a screen edge pan gesture! You will thus be much happier, I think, if you construct your tests like this:

```
    switch recognizer.state {
    case .Began:
        // ... do initial setup
        fallthrough // <-- TAKE NOTE
    case .Changed:
        // respond to changes
    default:break
    }
```

In that way, you will capture the missing datum and respond to it, and the jump will not be quite so bad.

I tried logging in both `began` and `changed` and my numbers (showing `translationInView` with *no* `setTranslation` back to zero) are this sort of thing:

```
began
changed
(-16.5, 0.0)
changed
(-41.5, 0.0)
changed
(-41.5, 0.0)
changed
(-58.5, 0.0)
```

(The first one, preceded by `began`, is the `fallthrough` execution of `changed`.) So yes, we do go from nothing to -41 very fast, but at least there is an intermediate value of -16.5 so it isn't quite so abrupt.

Also I should add that if there is a serious delay and jump it may well be that you have multiple conflicting gesture recognizers. If so, you can detect this fact by using delegate methods such as `gestureRecognizer:shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer:` - which will also let you prioritize between them and perhaps make the other g.r. give way sooner.

Comment: Very interesting. Didn't think of using fall through here, I've tried so many different options. Will test after dinner :)

Comment: I've tested it as you've suggested but unfortunately it remains the same. I've added an edit in my post stating the cause of it (I think). The edit is done with your suggestion as well, just didn't change the whole question.